# Changing flash files on screen by clicking a button

Tags: html, flash

I am trying to develop a way to change a flash file displayed on the screen to another file by clicking a button. I have been able to do this with `jpg` images, but I can't get it to work with `flash` files. Can anyone help? I would greatly appreciate it.

Below are two htmls:

1. The first one changes `jpg` images and it works
2. The second one I constructed to be similar to do the same with `flash` files but it does not work.

I had to put `//` on all the lines, otherwise when I submitted the question it was trying to execute the html. Thanks.

**Html 1. This changes Image 1 to Image 2 on click. It works**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeSrc()
        {
        document.getElementById("myImage").src="Image 2.jpg";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="myImage" src="Image 1.jpg" width="400" height="400" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="button" onclick="changeSrc()" value="Change image">
</body>
</html>
```

**Html 2. This is intended to change Flash 1 to Flash 2 on click. It does not work**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeSrc()
        {
        document.getElementById("myImage").src="Flash 2.swf";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" 
    id="myImage" width="450" height="335"> 
    <param name="movie"  value="Flash 1.swf" /> 
    </object> 
    <br /><br />
    <input type="button" onclick="changeSrc()" value="Change image">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. However, I made this work on IE but it is still not working in Firefox.

The code that works in IE are:

```
document.getElementById('Flash1').movie = 'flash2.swf';

document.Flash1.movie = "flash2.swf";

document.getElementById('Flash1').LoadMovie(0, 'flash2.swf');

document.getElementsByName("Flash1")[0].movie = 'flash2.swf';
```

Any code will work on IE, select the one you like.